# "The connection was not closed the connection's current state is open"

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, connection

I have a datagridview (unbound) which is populated from Access database. I have checkboxes which can be ticked and then deletes the records. I have added a sub called Update() which updates the availability of the member based on the ID deleted from the datagridview. The delete works perfectly when I comment out the Update() so I have identified the error

> The connection was not closed, the connection's current state is open

To be coming from this:

```
    Public Sub Update()

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvMember.Rows
        con.Open()
        If row.Cells(3).FormattedValue Then
            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Members SET Available = 1 WHERE ID = " & (row.Cells(3).FormattedValue) & "", con)
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
            End Using
        End If
    Next
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

I have tried almost everything.
i.e. 
`If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then con.Close()`

A day ago it was working fine and updating the available field in my database now it keeps coming up with that error and not deleting all the records. Am I missing something? Why is it doing this?

Comment: Typo, move the con.Open outside (before) the for each loop

Comment: I have, it's still showing the error :(

Comment: Then you have left the connection open somewhere. This is what happens when you use a global connection object. Use a local connection better inside a using statement. see the answer below

Comment: Still not working I don't understand..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem #1 - you're calling conn.open inside your loop.

Problem #2 - there's no error detection/error handling

Suggested alternative:

```
Public Sub Update()

try   
  con.Open()
  For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvMember.Rows
    If row.Cells(3).FormattedValue Then
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Members SET Available = 1 WHERE ID = " & (row.Cells(3).FormattedValue) & "", con)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
        End Using
    End If
  Next
Catch ex as Exception
  MsgBox("Can't load Web page" & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
Finally
  if (con.State = ConnectionState.Open) then conn.Close
End Sub
```

Additional suggestion: check your DataGrid properties in the MSVS IDE and make sure you're not also opening a connection there, as well.

Comment: Hello I have tried yours and it said "The connection was not closed. The connection current state is open"....

Comment: For some reason it only seems to do that though when I use my Tick All button and then delete??

Comment: @user3600024 - Excellent!  Progress!  1) Please keep the try/catch/finally, 2) Please look at my final suggestion (check the properties in the IDE) to see if the connection is already being opened before you hit "Update()".  Perhaps you don't need the "Open/Close" at all!  And please "upvote" this reply.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by "check properties in the IDE"?

Comment: I have just tried it again and it said "ExecuteNonQuery requires and open and available connection. The connection current state is closed"???

Comment: Hi - Clarification on "Look at the connection properties in your IDE": `Please 1) Go into your MSVS project 2) Design View 3) Select your DataGridView 4) Go the the "Properties" Pane for your DataGridView 5) Select "DataSource"`.  It's possible you've defined a data source that is *already* opening the connection, and conflicting with your "Update()" subroutine.  I hope that helps...

Comment: Hello, I've just checked and as I  don't use databindings it says "None" in the "DataSource"

Comment: I think I've fixed it but not sure. I just deleted the con.open() and con.close() and it doesn't show the error anymore and works!

Comment: Yup - it sounds like there was a conflict with another "open" that you happened to be doing somewhere else in your program.  Glad you got it squared away! TAKEWAY LESSONS: 1) Always consider error checking for any operation that might fail, 2) Always look at your loops - any operations you CAN move outside the loop, you generally SHOULD move outside the loop.  ALSO: please consider upvoting and/or accepting this response if you found it helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your help, helped me understand and learn new things :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, i solve problem by put con.open() out of loop

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend wrapping the connection in a using block:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
     //etc...
}
```

Alternatively, add a catch block to the try-finally:

```
conn.Open();

try
{

}
catch
{

}
finally
{
    conn.Close();
}
```